# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una celda mediante una concatenación de fila y columna en una hoja de calculo de Google?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Se tiene "algun valor" en la celda F1, se requiere obtener ese dato como una concatenación de la celda B3 y B4, en donde B3="F" y B4="1".

**Intento**:

Utilizar el operador & para realizar la concatenación.

```
="="&B3&B4
```

Dando resultado "=F1" como string más no el dato ubicado en dicha celda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Intenta con [INDIRECTO](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=es)

## Explicación

INDIRECTO convierte una cadena ya sea en notación A1 o R1C1 en una referencia.

En este caso la fórmula quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
=INDIRECTO(B3&B4)
```

Nótese que el operador `=` sólo se incluye una vez, y esto se hace al inicio de la fórmula.